# Eclipse Unable to Launch, the selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Tags: eclipse, svn

I am getting the above error when i try to launch a Project which i checked out from SVN Repository. When i make my own Java Project on eclipse with a main class everything works fine, but when i try to run the main class from my repository project i get the above message.

I did not have such a problem before. Repository projects were running fine, i got suddenly this error yesterday and after searching the internet i still can't fix it.

I have now 3 Projects on eclipse, **home** which is a java project made by me and two projects from repository **lech** and **kramerspitz**.

Under Run-> Run Configuration->Java Application->Project  Browse i see only the home Project which i made, although the two other repository projects are also in my workspace but they don't show up.  (Run As is empty)

Does anyone know what i should do? Re-installing Eclipse does not help, cause the problem remains.

The only difference i see is that the two repository projects are missing a .classpath file. Please help!

Hear are some pics:
[image: eclipse]
[image: Run Configuration]
[image: Project Selection]
[image: workspace]
[image: home Project made by me]
[image: kramerspitz repository project (cannot run main)]
[image: reversi repository project (cannot run main method)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it seems I can't just check out on the project from the SVN repository. I have to choose from the project a specific project to check out, then everything works fine.

Comment: had the same issue and could not find a solution. figured it out myself and wanted to post the solution on here. you already did that :)
it's a shame that i cannot checkout the whole teamproject (including conference/meetings,diagrams and the like). but each programing project works just fine as you stated.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes it happens when you forget to write "String[] args" in the main parenthesis

```java
public class Hello {
    public static void main(){
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

Code above would cause a similar problem

Comment: OMG how did I not notice that!, thank you so much. I wanted to see what error would be thrown if I run on command line as I felt I am wasting too much time and it had this same error mentioned

Answer (score 2):

I Windows 8 and run Eclipse C++ Kepler (Toolchain = MinGW).  This is what I did for the same message that you got and it worked for me:
In editor's screen, right-click>Run As>Local C/C++ Application

Answer (score 2):

Same problem find solution using

Run >> Run Configuration >> Android Application >>Under Project ....Select Brows Button to select appropriate project

now project run successfully

Thanks....

Comment: After selecting Browse, I see no project at all ! what to do ?

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Hello world!!!");
    }
}
```

Also if you omit the `static` keyword, the problem happens.